# How do I CASCADE DROP a table being referenced in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, foreign-key, cascade, drop-table

If I have a table that references another one

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x int PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE bar (
  x int,
  CONSTRAINT asdf FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES foo(x)
);

DROP TABLE foo;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

In PostgreSQL I can easily use [`DROP ... CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html)

> `CASCADE` Automatically drop objects that depend on the table (such as views), and in turn all objects that depend on those objects (see Section 5.13).

Like this,

```
# CREATE TABLE foo ( x int PRIMARY KEY );
# CREATE TABLE bar ( x int REFERENCES foo );
# DROP TABLE foo CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to constraint bar_x_fkey on table bar
DROP TABLE
```

However, in MySQL, even with `CASCADE` you get an error,

```
DROP TABLE foo CASCADE;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible yet to get around this, [from the MySQL docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/drop-table/)

> If a foreign key references this table, the table cannot be dropped. In this case, it is necessary to drop the foreign key first.

In fact `CASCADE` is explicitly documented in both [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/drop-table/) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html) as a NOOP,

> `RESTRICT` and `CASCADE` are allowed to make porting from other database systems easier. **In MariaDB, they do nothing.**

There is an issue on this as [MDEV-6907](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-6907) closed as "Won't Fix" that addresses this.

Comment: Another reason not to use MySQL!

Comment: @Vérace Friends don't let friends MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's how `CASCADE` works with MySQL derivatives!

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
( 
  x int PRIMARY KEY 
);

CREATE TABLE bar 
(
  x int,
  CONSTRAINT asdf FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES foo(x) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Some values:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3), (45), (7);
INSERT INTO bar VALUES(3), (3), (45), (7), (7);
```

Then:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE x = 3;
```

Now:

```
SELECT * FROM bar;

 x
 7
 7
45
```

So, (for the MySQL family) the DRI (Declarative Referential Integrity) works on the level of **records** and **not** on a table level. The referential constraint exists on the table bar and not on foo - therefore deleting foo has no effect on that constraint - and the system won't let you delete the parent **table**, but will let you delete the parent **record**.

Take a  look at the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8bdeb70fd3477f638c3f969dec247360) and it's fairly clear (and actually logical enough in one sense) if you reflect on it - at least to me it is!

**However**, a **big** caveat to the logic argument - PostgreSQL also [doesn't allow](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8bdeb70fd3477f638c3f969dec247360)

DROP TABLE foo;

but with a far more informative error message:

```
ERROR:  cannot drop table foo because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint asdf on table bar depends on table foo
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too
```

however

```
DROP TABLE foo CASCADE;
```

does [succeed](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=759c14b45233b9f752cb77021f6d0197).

So, MySQL fails on both statements, whereas PostgreSQL's solution is (IMHO and as usual) superior - it "forces" the `CASCADE` if it's explicitly invoked. MySQL won't let it delete under either circumstance.